# equivalence between jump and cmov

Tags: assembly, x86

If I had a label "branch" what is the difference between

```
je branch
```

and

```
cmove %eip branch
```

...also does this cause problems with branch prediction?

edit: cmov does allow immediate so just imagine its with a setcc or I set another register to branch and moved that.

Comment: The difference is that the second does not exist.

Comment: If you pick an ISA like ARM, then yes, a predicated `mov` to `pc` is possible, and presumably microarchitectures treat it the same as a conditional indirect branch.  (e.g. `movlt pc, r0`.) Or for an address with few enough significant bits, I guess `movlt pc, #0x40000` should be possible, unlike on x86 where `EIP` isn't a GPR, and `cmov` doesn't support immediate operands.

Comment: This makes no sense as an x86 question, unless you mean in a hypothetical sense with a new opcode that does the same thing as `je` (or with an absolute target?), or as just a source-level synonym for `je`.

Comment: I'm not very knowledgable about x86. I never learned that you cant do normal operations on the program counter. also I probably meant "sete" (from setcc)

Comment: `sete` can set an 8 bit register to `0` or`1`.  That wouldn't be a useful thing to do to EIP (or the low 8 bits of EIP?) even if it was usable as an operand for `setcc` or `cmov` (it isn't, unlike ARM where this could be a real question about actually valid instructions.)  `cmove %eax, %eip` if it existed would be a conditional indirect branch.  But it doesn't because EIP isn't one of the 8 general-purpose registers, like the linked duplicates explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot move values to the instruction pointer using any `mov` instructions. That is specific to jumps and calls.